# Why can't I get the inserted value of an input?

Tags: javascript, function

I have an input here with no default value set for, and I want to `console.log` the **inserted** value of the input when the button is clicked, but each time I click on the button, it logs empty, and not the inserted value of the input.

What might I be missing here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Color Box Creator</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<label>Please enter a color :
    <input type="text">
</label>
<br><br>
<button>CREATE</button>


<script>

    let value = document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).value ;

    // let valuePart = value.split(",") ;


    document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
        console.log(value) ;
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value when the user clicks. What you did in your code was just to take the value one time. This variable would not change . Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Color Box Creator</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<label>Please enter a color :
    <input type="text">
</label>
<br><br>
<button>CREATE</button>


<script>



    // let valuePart = value.split(",") ;


    document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
      
let value = document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).value ;
  console.log(value) ;
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you needed the `value` to be a global then you could also do this :

```js
    let value ;
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
      
      value = document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).value ;
      console.log(value) ;
    }
```

What you need to understand here is the scope and the lifecycle of a variable.

When you declare a variable like this

```js
    let value = document.getElementsByTagName("input").items(0).value
```

What you actually are doing is getting the value of the input element but only one time. That means that if the value of the input changes , it won't update the appropriate variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Color Box Creator</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<label>Please enter a color :
    <input type="text">
</label>
<br><br>
<button>CREATE</button>


<script>

    //let value = document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).value ;

    // let valuePart = value.split(",") ;


    document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
        let value = document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).value ;
        console.log(value) ;
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script, the variable `value` is assigned the value in the beginning and not when the button is clicked. Move this code into the `onclick` handler.

```
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
        let value = document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).value ;
        console.log(value) ;
    }
```